# MS SQL REPLACE based on 1 character to the left of the $

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replace

I am not a SQL expert so please forgive me if this is SQL 101 :).

In a select statement there are 2 replace functions. They look for a Servername and it's admin share d$ by it's UNC path. Example '\SERVERNAME\d$'
It then replaces '\SERVERNAME\d$' with 'D:'.

Here is the query currently:

```
select Replace(p.Path,'\\SERVERNAME\d$','D:') as searchpath
                 ,p.path as fullpath 
                 ,s.ShareName
                 ,s.SharePath
                 ,p.Member
                 ,p.Access         
   From   Paths As p
                 Left Outer Join Shares as s on
                              Replace(p.Path,'\\SERVERNAME\d$','D:') Like s.SharePath + '\%'
```

Up until now it has always been d$. 
Today my needs have changed and I need the query to find ANY servername UNC path admin share regardless of share letter (c$, d$, e$, f$...etc) and replace it with it's respective drive letter (D:, E:, F:... etc).

My thought is replace function could find the $ and look one character to the left of it to get the proper share letter, then use that for the replace. The issue I have, not being a SQL professional, is that I know SQL can likley do what I need it to do...I just don't know how to get there. I've googled and found some examples, but haven't had any luck in getting them to work. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What example did you try, and how did it not work?   Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx), [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx), [`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) to get what you want.

**Sample  Query**

```
DECLARE @ReplaceChar VARCHAR(100) = '[prefixcharacters]\\SERVERNAME\d$[postcharacter]'
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(100) = '\\SERVERNAME\_$'


SELECT 
STUFF(@ReplaceChar,PATINDEX('%' + @SearchString + '%',@ReplaceChar),LEN(@SearchString),
UPPER(SUBSTRING(@ReplaceChar,PATINDEX('%' + @SearchString + '%',@ReplaceChar) + LEN(@SearchString) - 2,1)) + ':') as searchpath
WHERE PATINDEX('%' + @SearchString + '%',@ReplaceChar) > 0
```

**Output**

```
[prefixcharacters]D:[postcharacter]
```

**Alternate Query**

You can shorten the query if you want to get the previous character before `$` as per your title. Something like this

```
DECLARE @ReplaceChar VARCHAR(100) = '[prefixcharacters]\\SERVERNAME\d$[postcharacter]'
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(100) = '\\SERVERNAME\_$'

SELECT
STUFF(@ReplaceChar,
    PATINDEX('%'+@SearchString+'%',@ReplaceChar),
    LEN(@SearchString),
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(@ReplaceChar,CHARINDEX('$',@ReplaceChar) -1,1)) + ':')
WHERE PATINDEX('%'+@SearchString+'%',@ReplaceChar) > 0
```

In this query

1. `STUFF` replaces your pattern with with the character before `$` + `':'`
2. Start of pattern is identified by `PATINDEX('%'+@SearchString+'%',@ReplaceChar)`
3. `D` is identified by getting the `charindex` of '$' and then getting the previous character using `SUBSTRING`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar (100)
SET @str = '\\SERVERNAME\d$'
IF @str LIKE '\\SERVERNAME\_$'
    SET @str = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@str, 14, 1)) + ':'
SELECT @str
```

Starting from previous, something like

```
select UPPER(SUBSTRING(p.path, 14, 1)) + ':' as searchpath
                 ,p.path as fullpath 
                 ,s.ShareName
                 ,s.SharePath
                 ,p.Member
                 ,p.Access         
   From   Paths As p
                 Left Outer Join Shares as s on
                              SUBSTRING(p.path, 14, 1) + ':' Like s.SharePath + '\%'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about ¸

```
select Replace(SUBSTRING(p.path, 14, Len(@spath)-14),'$',':') as searchpath
             ,p.path as fullpath 
             ,s.ShareName
             ,s.SharePath
             ,p.Member
             ,p.Access         
From   Paths As p
             Left Outer Join Shares as s on
                         Replace(SUBSTRING(p.path, 14, Len(@spath)-14),'$',':') Like s.SharePath + '\%
```

select  as searchpath

Answer (score 0):

I am no mysql expert either :)

Based on the logic you mentioned in the last part of the question, I have used concat and substring to get to the drive letter in the column.

Hope this helps

```
select replace(path, concat(substring(path, 1, locate('$', path) - 2),  substring(path, locate('$', path) - 1, 1) , '$'), concat(substring(path, locate('$', path) - 1, 1) , ':')) as searchpath ...
```

The remaining part of the query would be the same.